# how to develop automatic birthday reminder java program to display reminder message to different computer

Tags: java, javascript

I am planing to build java application which can remind the birthday of a person to all other person's in a group. My reminder program should run automatically at particular time on daily basis by checking back end database. If it found any person birth date is having today's date it should send reminder to all other person's desktop (Systems are connected by LAN)  by displaying alert box having persons name with birthday reminder info.
Please share your comments/ideas to shape more appropriate and guide me how to do it using java.

Comment: You could send an SMS or an email.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the client programm in the auto start. You ask your Server via TCP if there is any birthdays. If there is one, the server returns the data. If not, the programm closes , because its enough if you check once a day.

Then your server checks with the first request ( on a new day)  if there are any birthdays and if so, the server saves the birthdays. So you just have to call your database once a day. Also you have to check with every server call, if the date of the saved data is the current date, if not, you call the database.